# OpenFramework 0.9.2 : How can i get image.bpp value from OfImage?

Tags: c++, openframeworks

I get bpp is protected member of 'ofImage_

love to get number bits per pixel from loaded image, some idea how to get this number?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create an ofPixels object for you image, then you could access individual pixels with the objects name preceded by [num]. Then use the size() function to get the size.

There's a tutorial here http://openframeworks.cc/documentation/graphics/ofPixels/

Answer (score 0):

```
ofImage image;

// Load your image.

int bpp = image.getPixels().getBitsPerPixel();
```